MongoDB Entity Framework Core: Expression Must be Writeable
I'm using Entity Framework Core with MongoDB. However, I'm running into an issue when trying to use FirstOrDefault.
I have a base class, SignInCredentials:
public class SignInCredentials(string username, string? password)
{
    public string Username { get; set; } = username;
    public string? Password { get; protected init; } = password;
}

I extend it with Account:
public class Account : SignInCredentials
{
    // [Key] sets the primary key
    [Key]
    public ObjectId Id { get; private init; }

    private readonly byte[] salt;

    public Account(string username, string password) : base(username, null)
    {
        Id = new ObjectId();
        salt = GenerateSalt();
        Password = Hash(password, salt);
    }

    // More code not displayed
}

I store a DbSet<Account>, which is configured as:
modelBuilder.Entity<Account>().ToCollection("accounts");
However, when I try: accounts.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Username == creds.Username);, where creds is a SignInCredentials, I get the following error:
System.ArgumentException: Expression must be writeable (Parameter 'left')
         at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.RequiresCanWrite(Expression expression, String paramName)
         at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Assign(Expression left, Expression right)
         at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType binaryType, Expression left, Expression right, Boolean liftToNull, MethodInfo method, LambdaExpression conversion)
         at System.Linq.Expressions.BinaryExpression.Update(Expression left, LambdaExpression conversion, Expression right)
         at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression node)
         at MongoDB.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Visitors.ProjectionBindingRemovingExpressionVisitor.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression binaryExpression)

How do I fix this error?

Seems like it is related to this GitHub issue: EfCore 8: Primitive collections in JSON documents error with init. Either you not use init or update the Entity Framework Core to 8.0.1 version.

Using set instead of init fixed it. Could you add your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

A similar issue was reported: EfCore 8: Primitive collections in JSON documents error with init.
Either you should apply set rather than init.
public string? Password { get; protected set; } = password;

or you have to update the EF Core to 8.0.1 and above.
Note that: At this moment, MongoDB.EntityFrameworkCore (7.0) only supports EF Core 7 and .NET 7.
